# Цвет текста. PHP

Tags: php

Код

```
<?php
    printf("<span color='#%X%X%X'>Привет</span>", 65, 127, 245);
?>
```

выдает слово `Привет` но цвет черный. Почему?

Comment: Попробуйте: printf("<span style="color:'#%X%X%X;">Привет</span>", 65, 127, 245);

Comment: Нет выдает синтаксическую ошибку так как в вашем коде есть ошибки связанные с закрытием "

Comment: Да, извиняюсь. Лишняя кавычка: printf("<span style='color: #%X%X%X;'>Привет</span>", 65, 127, 245);

Comment: Этот вопрос больше касается не `PHP`, а основ - языка `HTML` и `CSS`. У тега `span` нет атрибута `color`. Цвет текста через `span` можно задать только в стилях. Пример:  https://puzzleweb.ru/html/tag_span.php

Comment: @TO220 Все же нет, не работает))

Comment: Ругается ошибкой или просто не подкрашивает?

Comment: @Самвел Попробуйте такой вариант:  printf("<span style='color: rgb(%X,%X,%X);'>Привет</span>", 65, 127, 245);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите аттрибут `style` и в нём уже `color`:

```
<?php
    printf("<span style='color: #%X%X%X'>Привет</span>", 65, 127, 245);
?>
```